# In a .net gridview can a template field populate a drop-downlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have data returning to a `Gridview` in .net from a dynamic database and one of the fields has a long list of semi-colon delimited values. I was able to display this data using line breaks in place of semi-colons however as there is potentially up to 20 values in this field I'm sure there's a better way of displaying this.

I used the following code to create and amend a template field:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amalgamation"
                    SortExpression="Amalgamation">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("Amalgamation").ToString().Replace(";", "<br />")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

An example of the data which will populate this field is: `100001;100002;600001;600006`.

**Update:** Ive tried this but had no joy. In the html:

`<%#PopulateArray((string)(Eval("Amalgamation")))%> 
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStrings" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>`

Then this function in the code behind:

```
public object PopulateArray(string s) 
{ 
string[] sArray = s.Split(';'); 
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList(); 
ddl = (DropDownList)this.Page.FindControl("ddlStrings"); 
ddl.DataSource = sArray; 
ddl.DataBind();
return sArray;
}
```

I get a NullReferenceException on the line: ddl.DataSource = sArray

Comment: Are you asking for suggestions on how it should appear, or on how to break up the data into some form of list?

Comment: Well I was really just asking if a dropdown was the best way to display this information and how would I go about it if it was. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I've got the bottom of it. I was referencing the ID for the Dropdown instead of referencing each row instance of it. I put the code in the row created event of the gridview using the parameter:

```
onrowcreated="ArrayDataView_RowCreated"
```

I split the result using the semi-colon delimiter every time a row was created in the table. I also cast each result using the object class ("MyData") I was using for the database. I then had to filter out the header and footer data rows of the gridview using an "if" statement. Here is the row created code in the code behind:

```
    protected void ArrayDataView_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlStrings");
            ddl.DataSource = (e.Row.DataItem as MyData).Amalgamation.Split(';');
        }       
    }
}
```

I dropped the eval function in the aspx page and the item template in the gridview was just reduced to housing the drop down:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStrings" AutoPostBack="false" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></ItemTemplate>
```

Thanks to all who helped!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you only want to display this data.  If you want the user to be able to edit the data but to be able to reassemble it into a delimited string, that's a much more complex problem -- so much so that you might want to reconsider how you are storing the data in the database.

The easiest way to turn a delimited string into an array of strings is to use the `String.Split` method:

```
string s = "111;333;555;";
string[] sParts = s.Split(";");
```

You might have to do this in code-behind, though, rather than in a binding expression, because you not only need to split the string, you probably want to bind it to something.  There are a number of options:  you might like the `BulletedList` web control.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Ann. Yeah I just want to display the data in a Gridview on a table snapshot page. I noticed the 20 items made that cell ridiculously big. I was hoping there was a better way to display it. I hoped the drop-down list would be the simplest. I liked the simplicity of just line breaking each item as it involved little coding in behind. So if I wrap a function around the eval and create the array in the code behind then bind that array to the dropdown? If so how would I bind the dropdown to the array from the code behind?

Answer (score 0):

Binding to a dropdown seems to be a good idea...if at all you need to edit this in `<EditItemTemplate>` , for displaying purpose this is good enough...

Comment: Great cheers for getting back to me on this one. I assume you mean something like this: 
<EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList id="DropDownList-Amal" runat="server">
         <asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
But how would I populate the values. Would I read the field in to an array in the code behind then loop through this to populate the dropdownlist?

Comment: @power2havenots Once you had the array, you could just use databinding to populate the drop down list.  Just a few lines of code, no looping required.  :)

Comment: @power2havenots as Ann L suggested after preparing array, DataSource property and DataBind Method of dropdownlist will help, and you will also need to specify DisplayMember and ValueMember property.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do that, but you wouldn't have to bind to a dropdown if it is just for display.  You could just add the markup to make a standard html dropdown list.

If you want to get fancy, how about a function that returns some html with a  which shows the first few items, a "..." if there are more, and some script to expand it to show the whole list when you mouseover the , or something like that?

Comment: Cheers Steve I think this will still require manipulation in the code behind page and an array would be the only way I can think of to dynamically populate the number of list items required each time. I like the javascript "show more" option as a bells and whistles on this solution though